# Error: Invalid 'path' argument to function

Tags: r

I have recently downloaded R (so should be the latest version). I am trying to create a function (`corr`) that reads in multiple csv files from a directory containing data on pollutants, and uses the complete cases in each file to return the correlation between the "sulfate" and "nitrate" columns. A threshold for the minimum number of complete cases is also used.

The function corr is created without any errors, but when I try to use it (try and run the bottom line of code) I get the error:

> Error in list.files(directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE) :
>   invalid 'path' argument

Below is the code I am trying:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  filenames3 <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
  loop_length <- length(filenames3)
  correlation_values <- numeric()

  for(i in loop_length) {

    read_in_data3 <- read.csv(filenames3[i])
    complete_boolean <- complete.cases(read_in_data3)
    nobs2 <- sum(complete_boolean) 
    data_rmNA <- read_in_data3[complete_boolean,] 

    if(nobs2 > threshold) {
      correlation_values <- c(correlation_values,
                              cor(data_rmNA[["sulfate"]], 
                                  data_rmNA[["nitrate"]]))
    }
  }
  correlation_values
}

corr("C:/Users/Danie/OneDrive/Documents/R/specdata")
```

I am new to R so it may be a basic mistake. The working directory is the same as in the last line of code, and contains all the csv data files. If I put `path=directory` in the first line of code then the error changes to:

> Error in list.files(directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE) :
>   object 'directory' not found

I don't understand this as the directory is specified as an argument in corr.

Really stuck on this and don't seem to be making any progress. Thanks in advance for any help!

Ps. First post, let me know if there's any etiquette rules that I've missed.

Comment: What do you get if you run the `list.files("C:/Users/Danie/OneDrive/Documents/R/specdata", pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)` line directly in the console?

Comment: It returns the full file names for all the .csv files.

Comment: I know the struggle working with paths in `r`. Can you try setting `directory <- file.path("C:", "Users", "Danie", "OneDrive", "Documents", "R", "specdata")` before the function?

Comment: Btw, just to make sure that this is not the root of the error: the User folder specified is named `Danie` and not `Daniel` (like your user name on SO). Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks, but the same error message persists.

Comment: And yes it is Danie. The directory works in the list.files function in the console so should be correct?

Comment: So you have used the `file.path` method as described before? And you also changed the function call below to use `directory` as the argument, correct? Strange. I have used file.path for a very similar function and there was no problem.
You could try to specify `pattern = "*.csv"` in the list of arguments of the function and substitute `pattern = "*.csv"`in the `list.file` call with `pattern`. Just to try it out.

Comment: Yes I have used the file.path method described and changed the argument in corr to directory. No luck trying with *.csv either.

Comment: What happens, when you intialize the variable `directory` with the `file.path` as described and change the arguments of `list.files` to `path=directory`?

Comment: What happens when you type `directory` (so the variable name, where you stored the file.path-value) in the console?

Comment: Ok, I've had some success. I exited and reopened R, and ran the code identical to as in the question, and it returns a value (although not a vector of several values as I would have hoped). If I change the code as you mentioned, it now also returns the same value. I assume the new issue I'm having is unrelated to the directory issue? Either way, running directory returns "C:/Users/Danie/OneDrive/Documents/R/specdata".

Comment: Okay, seems like you solved the problem (at least the path one). If you get stuck on the vector, you should consider opening up another question or try to solve it yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help!

Comment: Why did you post your question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128944/using-for-loop-in-a-function-only-returns-last-value/52129714#52129714