# Using for loop in a function, only returns last value

Tags: r

I am writing a function which takes a directory of data, and reads them in, and (if it reaches the threshold of complete cases), calculates the correlation between two variables in the data ("sulfate" and "nitrate"). I want this to run in a for loop to create a numeric vector of the correlation values (one value for each file in the directory).

However, when I run the code, it only returns the last value.

I am quite new to R (so may be making simple mistakes, and have the newest version of R installed). Below is the code:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  filenames3 <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
  loop_length <- length(filenames3)
  correlation_values <- numeric()

  for(i in loop_length) {

    read_in_data3 <- read.csv(filenames3[i])
    complete_boolean <- complete.cases(read_in_data3)
    nobs2 <- sum(complete_boolean) 
    data_rmNA <- read_in_data3[complete_boolean, ] 

    if(nobs2 > threshold) {
    correlation_values <- c(correlation_values,
                        cor(data_rmNA[["sulfate"]],
                            data_rmNA[["nitrate"]]))
    }
  }
  correlation_values
}

corr("C:/Users/Danie/OneDrive/Documents/R/specdata")
```

I have tried specifying the length of the vector e.g. `correlation_values <- numeric(length = loop_length)`. This returns a vector of the right length, but all the values are 0 excluding the last which runs properly. I have looked at similar questions, but still can't find a solution to my problem.

I assume I'm losing information in the loop somewhere (rewriting over a variable or something).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try `loop_length <- seq_along(filenames3)` instead. Also, before the loop do `correlation_values <- numeric(length(filenames3))` and in the loop `correlation_values[i] <- cor(etc)`.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I'm not sure why this question was voted down, but likely because it didn't have a reproducible example. However I voted it back up because it seems fine to me given that it is difficult to provide a reproducible example of a folder and enclosed files. In the future when something is hard to completely reproduce for a post, you could try also adding the values of key variables, like `loop_length`

Comment: Also, to avoid unexpected behavior it is good to add an explicit return at the end of your function. for example here that would be `return(correlation_values)`

Comment: Why did you post your question twice? Next time just edit the original. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52127834/error-invalid-path-argument-to-function/52129925#52129925

Comment: Thanks, either Rui Barradas' and rrr's solutions both worked. And noted, next time I will edit the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to say `for(i in 1:loop_length)` instead of `for(i in loop_length)`.

R will loop over each element in the provided vector, but right now your vector is length 1 which is why only the last value is returned.